# How to fix TikZ node's height with \heightof?

Tags: tikz-pgf, lengths

I can use `\widthof{text}` to fix a `minimum width` of a TikZ's node. I would like to use `\heightof{text}` to fix its `minimum height` but it doesn't work.

I just want to fill my nodes with one word but I want to draw some empty nodes with same height as filled ones. But I would like not to use a trial and error system to fix it's size.

Next code shows what I want to do. I've tried uncommenting `\usepackage{calc}` but nothing changed. `.log` file doesn't show any error about knowing or not command `\heightof`.

A possible solution would be to use `\vphantom{text}` inside empty nodes, but I would like to know what's wrong with this one.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
box/.style={draw,%
    minimum width=5mm,%
    minimum height=\heightof{Cap},%
    align=center},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small\sffamily]

\node[box] (h0) {Cap};
\foreach \i [remember=\i as \lastx (initially 0)] in {1,...,6} 
    \node[box,right= 0mm of h\lastx] (h\i) {};
\node[box,right=0mm of h\lastx] {cua};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the result. You can see that `minimum height` is not fixed with `\heightof`. Why?

[image]

Comment: Don't use `minimum height` (or add `\depthof` to `\heightof`). Use `text depth` *and* `text height`. For example: `text height=1em,text depth=.2em`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: OK, with `text height=\heightof{Cap}` and `text depth=\depthof{Cap}` I obtain equal height nodes, but why `minimum height=\heightof{Cap}` doesn't work? As you can see in my result empty nodes are shorter than `C`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Tom answered my question, If I fix `minimum heigth` I must include `inner sep` in it for empty nodes.

Comment: Actually, it seems to already do this, see my edit.

Answer (score 21):

The `minimum height` ist the total height, not taking into account the `inner sep` of the nodes. Setting the `outer sep` to zero will align them nicely:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\myinnersep}{2}% inner sep in mm

\tikzset{
box/.style={draw,%
        inner sep=\myinnersep,%
        outer sep=0,%
    minimum width=5mm,%
    minimum height=\heightof{Cap}+2*\myinnersep*1mm,%
    align=center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small\sffamily]

\node[box] (h0) {Cap};
\foreach \i [remember=\i as \lastx (initially 0)] in {1,...,6} 
    \node[box,right= 0mm of h\lastx] (h\i) {};
\node[box,right=0mm of h\lastx] {cua};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Understood! Do you know how to consider font size? Something like `\heightof{\Large{Cap}}`.

Comment: No, it doesn't consider fontsize. It works for you because you change `\myinnersep`. Try with `minimum height=\heigthof{Cap}+\depthof{Cap}` and `\myinnersep=0`, it should draw a 'tight' Cap box and it does only for `normalsize` font.

Comment: Nice solution. Can it be done generically? I.e. without having manually provide the contents of the largest node to the `minimum height`? But rather that it equalises the sizes of the boxes based on the largest node?

Comment: @FrederickNord: New questions made within comments have difficult visibility, it's better that you make it as a new question with link to this answer.

Comment: `heightof` is not longer working with TikZ, the new command is `height("Cap")`