# How do I get the height and depth of a box as a dimension?

Tags: boxes, dimensions

In order to avoid misalignment issues with `tikz` nodes I have decided to set the options `text height` and `text depth` so that all nodes have the same height and depth as a normal line of text.  According to Wikipedia, the standard height of a line of text is `.7\baselineskip` and the standard depth `.3\baselineskip`. Therefore I do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,text height=.7\baselineskip,text depth=.3\baselineskip] at (0,0) {x};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this means I have to remember these values.

Is there a command that would compute the height and depth of box that I can use in these circumstances? E.g. `text depth=\depthof\strut`.

## Note:

This question is very similar to [How to fix TikZ node's height with \heightof?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78288/how-to-fix-tikz-nodes-height-with-heightof).  However the solution given there involving the `calc` package no longer seems to work.

Comment: Package `calc` provides these commands: `\widthof{text}`, `\heightof{text}`, `\depthof{text}`, and `\totalheightof{text}` (sum of height and depth). Could this be what you are looking for?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, this could be it. There's a related question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78288/how-to-fix-tikz-nodes-height-with-heightof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\strutbox` as a frame of reference. Here is some reference material:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{2em}{\baselineskip}} % Your reference
\fbox{\usebox\strutbox} % \strutbox
\fbox{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{2em}{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}}% \strutbox height/depth

\end{document}
```

- The first box has a depth of `.3\baselineskip` and a *total* height of `\baselineskip` (implying a height of `.7\baselineskip`), similar to what you're using.
- The second box prints `\strutbox` (a zero-width box with height/depth of a `\strut`).
- The third box replicates the first using `\strutbox` as a measure.

The above shows that you should be able to use `\ht\strutbox` (the `h`eigh`t` of `\strutbox`) for `text height` and `\dp\strutbox` (the `d`e`p`th of `\strutbox`) for `text depth`.

Comment: As long as there are no sub- or superscripts or other edge cases :)

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Without any packages:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
\setbox0\hbox{foo}
\begin{tabular}[]{ll}
  width & \the\wd0\\
  depth & \the\dp0\\
  height & \the\ht0
\end{tabular}

\setbox0\hbox{goo}
\begin{tabular}[]{ll}
  width & \the\wd0\\
  depth & \the\dp0\\
  height & \the\ht0
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\setbox` is not expandable. You might use `\vbox` if `\hbox` doesn't work with the contents you need, but the width doesn't work that way (ends up as `\linewidth`)

Comment: Thanks. This seems much more intricate than the solution that uses `\baselineskip` though.

Comment: @ErnestA well I just answered the question formulated by your title without reading much of your question :) You could as well insert some `\strut`s if all the nodes are one line -- though the answer in the possible duplicate looks like the way to go.